# SPRING JPA - org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've been stuck here for almost a week trying find the answer on the internet but sadly nothing worked. :( Everytime I try to update using this method:

```
private Tenant updateTenantWithApplicationProperties(List<TenantApplicationProperty> newTenantApplicationProperties, String tenantId) {
    String reason = "Update application properties.";
    Tenant existingTenant = tenantRepository.findById(tenantId);

    List<TenantApplicationProperty> temp = existingTenant.getTenantApplicationProperties();
    existingTenant.setTenantApplicationProperties(newTenantApplicationProperties);

    setApplicationPropertiesUpdateValues(temp, existingTenant);

    if(newTenantApplicationProperties != null && newTenantApplicationProperties.size() != 0) {
        Tenant savedTenantWithAppProps = saveTenantWithLog(existingTenant, reason);
        return savedTenantWithAppProps;
    }
    return existingTenant;
}
```

Im always getting this error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException:       org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity.ApplicationProperty
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1361)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1289)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1295)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:876)
```

But when Im using this method it works fine:

```
public Tenant updateTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        List<Database> databases = tenant.getDatabases();
        List<Administrator> administrators = tenant.getAdministrators();

        validateUpdateTenant(tenant);
        validateDatabases(databases);
        validateAdministrators(administrators);

        Tenant existingTenant = findByIdWithAllDetails(tenant.getId());
        List<Database> listExistingDatabases = existingTenant.getDatabases();
        Database existingEcomDb = getDatabaseByType(listExistingDatabases,
                TenantManagerConstants.ECOM_DATASOURCE);
        setDatabaseUpdateValues(listExistingDatabases, tenant);
        setAdministratorsUpdateValues(existingTenant.getAdministrators(),
                tenant);
        setProductUpdateValue(existingTenant.getProduct(), tenant);
            setApplicationPropertiesUpdateValues(existingTenant.getTenantApplicationProperties(), tenant);
        setEcomDBParamsDefaultValues(tenant);
        setAdministratorDefaultValues(tenant);
        Database updateEcomDb = getDatabaseByType(tenant.getDatabases(),
                TenantManagerConstants.ECOM_DATASOURCE);

        Boolean shouldInstallNewDB = true;
        if (existingEcomDb.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(updateEcomDb.getName())
                && existingEcomDb.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        updateEcomDb.getHost())
                && existingEcomDb.getPort().equals(updateEcomDb.getPort())) {
            shouldInstallNewDB = false;
        } else {
            testEcomDBConnection(updateEcomDb);
        }
        int ecomDbTableCount = getEcomDBTableCount(updateEcomDb);
        String[][] languages = formatAndValidateLanguages(updateEcomDb
                .getEcomDatabaseParameters().getLanguages());
        Tenant updatedTenant = saveExistingTenant(tenant);

        if (updatedTenant != null) {
            if (shouldInstallNewDB || ecomDbTableCount == 0) {
                installDatabase(updateEcomDb, languages, updatedTenant);
            } else {
                updateDatabase(updateEcomDb, languages, updatedTenant);
            }
            storageService.updateTenantFolderStructure(updatedTenant);
        } else {
            throw new TenantManagerException(
                    ApiMessageConstants.M_TENANT_PROVISION_ERROR,
                    ApiMessageConstants.C_TENANT_PROVISION_ERROR);
        }

        return updatedTenant;
    }
```

So here is my complete codes:

Tenant.java

```
package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.constant.TenantManagerConstants;
import com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.constant.TenantStatusEnum;

@Entity
@Table(name="tenant")
@XmlRootElement(name = "Tenant",namespace = "http://com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager/Tenant")
public class Tenant extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6687293822212120396L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String displayName;

    private String description;

    private String url;

    private String apiKey;

    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Database> databases;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Activity> activites;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Administrator> administrators;

    private String message;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TenantApplicationProperty> tenantApplicationProperties;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "tenant", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Product product;

    public Database findEcomDatabase() {
        Database database = null;
        if(databases != null) {
            for(Database db : databases) {
                if(db.getDatasource() != null) {
                    if(TenantManagerConstants.ECOM_DATASOURCE.equals(db.getDatasource().getName())) {
                        database = db;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return database;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(TenantStatusEnum statusEnum) {
        this.status = statusEnum.name();
    }

    public List<Database> getDatabases() {
        return databases;
    }

    public void setDatabases(List<Database> databases) {
        this.databases = databases;
    }

    public void addDatabase(Database database) {
        if (this.databases == null) {
            this.databases = new ArrayList<Database>(); 
        }
        database.setTenant(this);
        this.databases.add(database);
    }

    public List<Activity> getActivites() {
        return activites;
    }

    public void setActivites(List<Activity> activities) {
        this.activites = activities;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Administrator> getAdministrators() {
        return this.administrators;
    }

    public void setAdministrators(List<Administrator> administrators) {
        for (Administrator admin:administrators) {
            admin.setTenant(this);
        }
        this.administrators = administrators;
    }

    public void addAdministrator(Administrator administrator) {
        if (this.administrators == null) {
            this.administrators = new ArrayList<Administrator>(); 
        }
        administrator.setTenant(this);
        this.administrators.add(administrator);
    }

    public List<TenantApplicationProperty> getTenantApplicationProperties() {
        return tenantApplicationProperties;
    }

    public void setTenantApplicationProperties(
            List<TenantApplicationProperty> tenantApplicationProperties) {
        this.tenantApplicationProperties = tenantApplicationProperties;
    }

        public void addTenantApplicationProperty(TenantApplicationProperty tenantApplicationProperty) {
            if (this.tenantApplicationProperties == null) {
                    this.tenantApplicationProperties = new ArrayList<TenantApplicationProperty>(); 
            }
            tenantApplicationProperty.setTenant(this);
            this.tenantApplicationProperties.add(tenantApplicationProperty);
        }   

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        product.setTenant(this);
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

TenantApplicationProperty.java

```
package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity.pk.TenantApplicationPropertyPK;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tenant_application_property")
@IdClass(TenantApplicationPropertyPK.class)
public class TenantApplicationProperty extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenant_id")
    private Tenant tenant;

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "application_property_id")
    private ApplicationProperty applicationProperty;

    private String value;

    public TenantApplicationProperty() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Added constructor to handle custom query for
     * findByTenantIdApplicationPropertyName. No need to retrieve Tenant and
     * ApplicationProperty
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    public TenantApplicationProperty(String value) {
        setTenant(null);
        setApplicationProperty(null);
        setValue(value);
    }

    public Tenant getTenant() {
        return tenant;
    }

    public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public ApplicationProperty getApplicationProperty() {
        return applicationProperty;
    }

    public void setApplicationProperty(ApplicationProperty applicationProperty) {
        this.applicationProperty = applicationProperty;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((applicationProperty == null) ? 0 : applicationProperty
                        .hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (this == object)
            return true;
        if (object == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != object.getClass())
            return false;

        TenantApplicationProperty tenantAppProp = (TenantApplicationProperty) object;
        if (applicationProperty == null) {
            if (tenantAppProp.applicationProperty != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!applicationProperty.getApplicationPropertyGroup().getName().equals(tenantAppProp.applicationProperty.getApplicationPropertyGroup().getName())
                    || !applicationProperty.getName().equals(tenantAppProp.applicationProperty.getName())) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

TenanatApplicationPropertyPK.java

```
package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity.pk;

public class TenantApplicationPropertyPK implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String tenant;

    private Integer applicationProperty;

    public String getTenantId() {
        return tenant;
    }

    public void setTenantId(String tenant) {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }

    public Integer getApplicationPropertyId() {
        return applicationProperty;
    }

    public void setApplicationPropertyId(Integer applicationProperty) {
        this.applicationProperty = applicationProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((applicationProperty == null) ? 0 : applicationProperty
                        .hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((tenant == null) ? 0 : tenant.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        TenantApplicationPropertyPK tenantAppPropPK = (TenantApplicationPropertyPK) obj;
        if (applicationProperty == null) {
            if (tenantAppPropPK.applicationProperty != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!applicationProperty
                .equals(tenantAppPropPK.applicationProperty)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (tenant == null) {
            if (tenantAppPropPK.tenant != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!tenant.equals(tenantAppPropPK.tenant)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

ApplicationProperty.java

```
    package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "application_property")
    public class ApplicationProperty extends BaseModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        private String name;

        private String defaultValue;

        private boolean isVisible;

        private boolean clientVisible;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "property_group_id")
        private ApplicationPropertyGroup applicationPropertyGroup;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "property_type_id")
        private ApplicationPropertyType applicationPropertyType;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDefaultValue() {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        public void setDefaultValue(String defaultValue) {
            this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
        }

        public boolean getIsVisible() {
            return isVisible;
        }

        public void setIsVisible(boolean isVisible) {
            this.isVisible = isVisible;
        }

        public boolean getClientVisible() {
            return clientVisible;
        }

        public void setClientVisible(boolean clientVisible) {
            this.clientVisible = clientVisible;
        }

        public ApplicationPropertyGroup getApplicationPropertyGroup() {
            return applicationPropertyGroup;
        }

        public void setApplicationPropertyGroup(ApplicationPropertyGroup applicationPropertyGroup) {
            this.applicationPropertyGroup = applicationPropertyGroup;
        }

        public ApplicationPropertyType getApplicationPropertyType() {
            return applicationPropertyType;
        }

        public void setApplicationPropertyType(ApplicationPropertyType applicationPropertyType) {
            this.applicationPropertyType = applicationPropertyType;
        }

    }
```

ApplicationPropertyGroup.java

```
package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "application_property_group")
public class ApplicationPropertyGroup extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

ApplicationPropertyType.java

```
package com.infor.ecom.tenant.manager.model.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "application_property_type")
public class ApplicationPropertyType extends BaseModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

TenantServiceImpl.java

```
private Tenant updateTenantWithApplicationProperties(List<TenantApplicationProperty> newTenantApplicationProperties, String tenantId) {
    String reason = "Update application properties.";
    Tenant existingTenant = tenantRepository.findById(tenantId);

    List<TenantApplicationProperty> temp = existingTenant.getTenantApplicationProperties();
    existingTenant.setTenantApplicationProperties(newTenantApplicationProperties);

    setApplicationPropertiesUpdateValues(temp, existingTenant);

    if(newTenantApplicationProperties != null && newTenantApplicationProperties.size() != 0) {
        Tenant savedTenantWithAppProps = saveTenantWithLog(existingTenant, reason);
        return savedTenantWithAppProps;
    }
    return existingTenant;
} 

private Tenant saveTenantWithLog(Tenant tenant, String reason) {
    Tenant updatedTenant = tenantRepository.save(tenant);
    TenantLog tenantLog = new TenantLog();

    tenantLog.setTenantId(updatedTenant.getId());
    tenantLog.setDisplayName(updatedTenant.getDisplayName());
    tenantLog.setDescription(updatedTenant.getDescription());
    tenantLog.setUrl(updatedTenant.getUrl());
    tenantLog.setApiKey(updatedTenant.getApiKey());
    tenantLog.setStatus(TenantStatusEnum.valueOf(updatedTenant.getStatus()));
    tenantLog.setReason(reason);
    tenantLog.setMessage(updatedTenant.getMessage());
    tenantLogRepository.save(tenantLog);

    return updatedTenant;
}   

private void setApplicationPropertiesUpdateValues(List<TenantApplicationProperty> existingTenantAppProps, Tenant tenant) {
    List<TenantApplicationProperty> newTenantApplicationProperties = (tenant.getTenantApplicationProperties() != null) ? tenant.getTenantApplicationProperties() : new ArrayList<TenantApplicationProperty>();

    if(newTenantApplicationProperties.size() != 0) {
        for(TenantApplicationProperty tenantAppProp : newTenantApplicationProperties) {
            int index = existingTenantAppProps.indexOf(tenantAppProp);      
            if (index < 0) {
                // throw an error -- tenantAppProp should always exist, right?
            } else {
                existingTenantAppProps.get(index).setValue(tenantAppProp.getValue());
            }
        }
        tenant.setTenantApplicationProperties(existingTenantAppProps);
    }
}

public Tenant updateTenant(Tenant tenant) {
        List<Database> databases = tenant.getDatabases();
        List<Administrator> administrators = tenant.getAdministrators();

        validateUpdateTenant(tenant);
        validateDatabases(databases);
        validateAdministrators(administrators);

        Tenant existingTenant = findByIdWithAllDetails(tenant.getId());
        List<Database> listExistingDatabases = existingTenant.getDatabases();
        Database existingEcomDb = getDatabaseByType(listExistingDatabases,
                TenantManagerConstants.ECOM_DATASOURCE);
        setDatabaseUpdateValues(listExistingDatabases, tenant);
        setAdministratorsUpdateValues(existingTenant.getAdministrators(),
                tenant);
        setProductUpdateValue(existingTenant.getProduct(), tenant);
            setApplicationPropertiesUpdateValues(existingTenant.getTenantApplicationProperties(), tenant);
        setEcomDBParamsDefaultValues(tenant);
        setAdministratorDefaultValues(tenant);
        Database updateEcomDb = getDatabaseByType(tenant.getDatabases(),
                TenantManagerConstants.ECOM_DATASOURCE);

        Boolean shouldInstallNewDB = true;
        if (existingEcomDb.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(updateEcomDb.getName())
                && existingEcomDb.getHost().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        updateEcomDb.getHost())
                && existingEcomDb.getPort().equals(updateEcomDb.getPort())) {
            shouldInstallNewDB = false;
        } else {
            testEcomDBConnection(updateEcomDb);
        }
        int ecomDbTableCount = getEcomDBTableCount(updateEcomDb);
        String[][] languages = formatAndValidateLanguages(updateEcomDb
                .getEcomDatabaseParameters().getLanguages());
        Tenant updatedTenant = saveExistingTenant(tenant);

        if (updatedTenant != null) {
            if (shouldInstallNewDB || ecomDbTableCount == 0) {
                installDatabase(updateEcomDb, languages, updatedTenant);
            } else {
                updateDatabase(updateEcomDb, languages, updatedTenant);
            }
            storageService.updateTenantFolderStructure(updatedTenant);
        } else {
            throw new TenantManagerException(
                    ApiMessageConstants.M_TENANT_PROVISION_ERROR,
                    ApiMessageConstants.C_TENANT_PROVISION_ERROR);
        }

        return updatedTenant;
    }

private Tenant saveExistingTenant(Tenant tenant) {
    tenant.setStatus(TenantStatusEnum.INPROGRESS);
    tenant.setMessage(ApiMessageConstants.M_DATABASE_UPDATE_INPROGRESS);
    String reason = ApiMessageConstants.R_UPDATE_TENANT;
    return saveTenantWithLog(tenant, reason);
}
```

Comment: paste ApplicationPropertyGroup  and ApplicationPropertyType

Comment: hi SMA, i've already added ApplicationPropertyGroup and ApplicationPropertyType.

Comment: hi again SMA, i forgot to add some scenarios.. here is the final code. please check it. :)

Comment: i have already answered below.. please check that out.

Comment: Please, provide a MINIMAL working example. SO is not a dump-your-code site.

Comment: hmm but that's the most minimal codes that i can give.

Answer (score 0):

In application property, you defined 1-1 relation like:

```
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_group_id")
    private ApplicationPropertyGroup applicationPropertyGroup;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_type_id")
    private ApplicationPropertyType applicationPropertyType;
```

While you have not defined the same relation (note it should work bidirectionally i.e. say for e.g. if you as a person related to an employee id, then employee id is related to you as a person well) in individual property ApplicationPropertyGroup and ApplicationPropertyType.

You should add the same 1-1 relation in ApplicationPropertyGroup and ApplicationPropertyType with ApplicationProperty.

Comment: hmm but in my case i dont want to make it a bidirectional in ApplicationProperty to ApplicationPropertyGroup and ApplicationPropertyType. and also in TenantApplicationProperty to ApplicationProperty. Primarily i just to update the TenantApplicationProperty entity which has the application property, tenant and value. hmm do you have some thoughts about this?